# Query MySQL em PHP só funciona localmente

Tags: php, mysql

É o seguinte: o sistema que estou dando manutenção estava usando dois tipos de query (não me perguntem o porquê) e localmente (localhost) funcionam perfeitamente. Quando subi o projeto para o servidor, as querys declaradas assim:

```
<?php $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO entrada_produto (id_produto, descricao, qtde, valor_unitario, unidade, cd, data_entrada) VALUES ('{$id_produto}', '{$descricao}', '{$qtde}', '{$valor_unitario}', '{$unidade}', '{$cd}', now())") or die(); ?>
```

Não funcionam. Apresentam o seguinte erro:

```
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user.........
```

Comment: Você fez importação da tabela do banco de dados no server?

Comment: Olá, eu fiz a exportação local e importei para o banco de dados no servidor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Por segurança, muitas instalações padrão e hospedeiros web configuram o usuário padrão do MySQL como sendo `usuario@localhost`, ou seja, somente acesso local.

Se você tem acesso administrativo ao servidor, precisa adicionar o acesso a `usuario@%` para acessar de qualquer lugar (o % é o "coringa", permitindo acesso de qualquer host); ou mesmo `usuario@PREENCHA_SEU_HOST_ESPECIFICO` por exemplo, se precisar de acesso externo apenas por uma máquina.

Um exemplo de comando para autorizar um usuário em qualquer host e em todas as tabelas:

```sql
CREATE USER 'meuusuario'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'senhadousuario';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'meuusuario'@'%';
```

Notar que nem sempre você quer todos os privilégios para o usuário, então convém granular melhor o acesso, conforme a intenção de uso. Veja mais detalhes na [documentação do grant](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)<sup>(en)</sup>.

> Se você não tem acesso administrativo, tente a alteração com o suporte da sua hospedagem.

Comment: Valeu, obrigado pela dica amigo.

Answer (score 1):

> Access denied for user...

Está falando que o usuário que você está usando não tem acesso.
Verifique os dados de acesso (host, user e password), a configuração do servidor deve ser diferente da sua configuração local.

Comment: Ai que está o problema. A conexão é feita com uma classe de conexão:

<?php Connection::getInstance()->connect($username, $password, $database); ?>

Comment: @piters Você já tento acessar o banco remotamente por um terminal usando mysql mesmo? Pode ser que o usuário/senha estão diferentes

Comment: Ainda assim, em algum lugar você precisa colocar os dados de acesso... O erro que passou está dizendo que as credenciais estão erradas, você tem acesso ao arquivo de configuração?

Comment: Sim tenho acesso, antes desse Connection tem esses dados:  

$username = 'user';  
$password = 'senha';    
$database = 'banco_de_dados';

Comment: Beleza, e consegue acessar o banco de dados do servidor por alguma interface (web ou remota)?

Comment: Sim consigo, pela web (phpMyAdmin).

Comment: E o usuário, senha e database são os mesmos do aquivo que você verificou?