# Erro mysqli_connect(): (42000/1044): Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql

Este codigo esta a dar erro.

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (42000/1044): Access denied for user 'u469236901_roota'@'10.2.1.41' to database 'u469236901_sysU' in /home/u469236901/public_html/RegisterUnity.php on line 7
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/u469236901/public_html/RegisterUnity.php on line 7
> Error

Quero fazer um sistema de register e login na unity.

```
<?php
    
$email = $_POST['email'];
$nome = $_POST['name'];
$senha = $_POST['passoword'];

$con = mysql_connect("mysql.hostinger.com.br","usuario_retirado","senha_retirada") or die("Error " . mysql_error($con));

$check = "SELECT * FROM SystemLR_unity" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysql_error($link));
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($check);
$result = mysqli_query($con, $check); 
if ($numrows > 0)
{

    $senha = md5($senha);
    $ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO SystemLR_unity (  `id` ,  `email` ,  `nome` ,  `senha` ) VALUES ('' ,  '".$email."' ,  '".$nome."' ,  '".$senha."') ; ");
    if ($ins)
        die ("User Criado Com Susseco!");
    else
        die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
    
}
else
{
    die("Este User Ja Existe!");
}


?>
```

Comment: Este erro ocorrer quando o seu usuário e senha estão errados ou o usuário que você criou não tem privilégios, se você está tentando conectar ao host via localhost, o ip da sua casa provavelmente não está liberado.

Comment: Provavelmente o erro está no nível de acesso do seu usuário. Testei o código e conectou normalmente no meu servidor local!

Comment: Acredito que [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4681/91) resolva o problema

Comment: Você deixou seu nome de usuário e senha expostos no código, removi-os para sua segurança. Tome cuidado ao expor essa informação, revise seu código antes de colocar na internet.

Comment: Sobre o mesmo problema [Query MySQL em PHP só funciona localmente](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5318/91) e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tive o mesmo problema 2 horas atrás e também foi na hostinger :O Para resolver o problema fiz o seguinte: Deixei a senha da hospedagem e do mysql iguais e troquei mysql.hostinger.com.br por localhost

Comment: A alteração para localhost é que deve ter resolvido. O MySQL autoriza acesso por usuário e host.

Comment: Obrigado, fusionou eu trocei a pass e o host e fusionou, mas continua aparecer um erro       Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u469236901/public_html/RegisterUnity.php on line 7
User Criado Com Susseco!

Comment: @Vralago Boa tarde, se traduzir a mensagem terá algo como: *mysql_connect está em desuso e será removido no futuro, use mysqli ou PDO em seu lugar*, o uso da api `mysql_*` será descontinuado, em seu lugar você pode usar a nova API chamada `mysqli` ou a classe `PDO`.