# Mysqli com acesso negado mesmo com configurações corretas

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou tendo um erro incomum para mim. Seguinte: quando tento conectar via mysqli recebo retorno de falha na autenticação ( acesso negado ), sendo que os parâmetros estão todos corretos! Para confirmar isso acesso normalmente através de console SSH com os mesmos parâmetros e tenho sucesso, mas o mysqli não funciona! O que poderia ser?

OBS: a extensão está habilitada no arquivo de configuração do php

O código de conexão é simples:

```
    $host = "localhost"
    $user = 'usuario';
    $password = 'senha';
    $db = ' banco';

    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        print("Conexão falhou: %s\n" . mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();

    }
```

O retorno que tenho é:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): : Access denied for user 'usuario'@'localhost' to database ' banco' in /fakepath/arquivo.php on line 14
Conexão falhou: %s Access denied for user 'usuario'@'localhost' to database ' banco'
```

Comment: O usuário tem permissão nesse banco? Permissões locais, permissões para acesso remoto, etc. Pq vc não tenta fazer login com o root pra rever as permissões?

Comment: Sim. Todas as permissões. Chequei aqui,  Inclusive quando faço acesso normal, console, via ssh, consigo fazer DDL e DML normalmente. O mysql remoto também está habilitado. O unico que não funciona é o mysqli...

Comment: Provavelmente seu problema é esse: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5303/query-mysql-em-php-s%c3%b3-funciona-localmente

Comment: Quando menciono mysql remoto, digo que as permissões para conexão de script em outra máquina também está habilitado. O serviço de mysql está rodando no servidor mas eu posso conectá-lo de outro local, setando mysql remoto. Ok. quando eu falo em ssh digo que consigo utilizar com o usuário mencionado e o banco que estou tentando acessar pelo php. Sò não funciona no PHP. Estou averiguando

Comment: Resolvi o problema! Algo estranho que eu ainda não tinha passado... Agradeço a você pelas dicas. Postarei como resolvi.

Answer (score 1):

```
seu código tem alguns erros:
1 - falta ; no fim da primeira linha
    correto $host = "localhost";
2 - $db=' banco'; tem espaço antes de banco
    correto $db='banco'; 

$host = "localhost"
    $user = 'usuario';
    $password = 'senha';
    $db = ' banco';
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! No caso, esse código com esses parâmetros foram apenas de exemplo. NO código real, com os parâmetros está tudo direitinho! Obrigado. E também consegui resolver

Answer (score 1):

Problema resolvido! Bom, observando tal erro, tentei conectar de formas distintas. O meu problema era sempre a conexão direta, ou seja, sempre que eu instanciava um objeto mysqli passando todos os parametros( inclusive o nome do banco a conectar ) dava erro de acesso negado. Então eu instanciei o objeto apenas com dados de conexao e usuario e utilizei a função "select_db" para selecionar após estar conectado. O código, com os mesmos parametros de antes, funcionou perfeitamente. Ficou dessa forma:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'usuario';
$password = 'senha';
$db = 'banco';

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password) OR DIE(mysqli_connect_error());

if ($mysqli->select_db( $banco )) {
    echo "selecionado";
    //query de teste
} else {
    exit();
}
```